# How can I use enter/br/ or \n in getElementById("ErrorTable").innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, html

Hello guys I might need you help with something I can not figure it out.

I have a registeration form and recently I added a red table for the errors in the filling inputs, but now I have a new problem and all the errors are in one row and I don't know how can I do "enter" to it and get it down so it will be in a list and not one by one right to left.

```
document.getElementById("ErrorTable").innerHTML += '•Agree with the terms';
```

and this is the table HTML:

```
    <center>
         <div class="RegisterTextArea">
            <table id="ErrorTable">

            </table>
         </div>
    </center>
```

**I have a new problem Here**: http://prntscr.com/7bxe6k.
How to clear the UL so it doesn't submit again like the picture and how to fit it in the box so it will split left when there is no space.

HTML:

```
<center>
     <div class="errors">
        <ul id="ErrorTable"></ul>
     </div>
</center>
```

style:

```
.errors
{
background-color: #FFB6B6;
border: groove 1px #A81B1B;
width: 500px; 
height: 50px;
text-align: right;
font-size: 10px;
color: #A81B1B;
}

.errors ul li
{

}
```

Comment: If it's just a text 'enter' you're wanting, you can use the [break tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br) `<br>`

Comment: Just concatenate `<br />` tag to the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use Unordered Html List instead of Table. I've updated your code as below

HTML

```
<center>
     <div class="RegisterTextArea">
        <ul id="ErrorTable">
        </ul>
     </div>
</center>
```

Java Script

```
    document.getElementById("ErrorTable").innerHTML = '';
    document.getElementById("ErrorTable").innerHTML += '<li>Agree with the terms</li>';
```

Hope you are expected such a result.

Comment: Its working but there is another problem, when u send the form and you see all the errors, you can send it again and it will overwrite again the errors with the old errors like:

-Agree with the terms
-Agree with the terms

Comment: @Ranb,  I've updated the answer. Hope you will reach your need with this answer.

Comment: It works! I just put it above the form and it works perfect!

But one last problem, it's getting out of the box when there are too many texts.

Comment: Update: I put a display style in the RegisterTextArea CSS:

display: table-header-group;

and it works great, as I wanted but one problem with that, the border doesn't show himself. Its just a red box with all the text but no border around the box.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a list, then you need to use **a list** and not a table.

```
<ul id="errors">

</ul>
```

You can't put text directly in a list (or in a table); you have to wrap it in appropriate markup. In the case of a list, that is a list item.

```
function add_error( error_message ) {
    var list_item = document.createElement('li');
    var text = document.createTextNode(error_message);
    list_item.appendChild(text);
    document.getElementByid('errors').appendChild(list_item);
}

add_error("Agree with the terms");
```

The default rendering of an unordered list puts each list item on a new line and gives it a bullet point.